# Quick find (ctrl+f) inside hidden div

Tags: javascript, html, css, search, full-text-search

I have a page with tabs implemented, where the inactive tabs are hidden with display:none. Now I'm trying to find a way to search in these hidden divs using the browsers quickfind (ctrl+f / cmd+f)

Is there e.g. a way to run javascript, whenever a user searches for something? If for example a user searches for «template» and it's found only in one of the inactive tabs, I'd like to activate/show that tab.

Is there a way? Or would I have to implement an own search filter?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't think intercepting the browsers' find mechanisms is the way to go. Can't you just put a search box on the page and handle that with Javascript?

Answer (score 1):

Well you can sure ask for the keyboard shortcuts but they can still use the browser menu to start searching.

Wouldn't it be easier to use a different method to hide those tabs? Something like

```
display: block;
height: 0;
width: 0;
overflow hidden;
```

for example (depends on you special markup/css of course)

Comment: the searched element should get focus by the search (I never tried something like this so you might experiment with it) but at least the text stays searchable...

Comment: I think it would be nice to ask for the keyboard shortcuts. And then automatically un-hide all hidden content (e.g. open all  `$(this).next().slideToggle("slow"); }).next().hide();`-Togglers, which might be hidden). That would be great, then the user can still have the choice whether to browse only visible content via the browser menu.

Comment: but I don't think that a user will notice the difference between a search by ctrl+f or browser menu->search. He will just wonder why he gets different results.

Comment: Nice point, this could be clarified. If one has a lot of such hidden togglers that become visible on *CTRL+F*, then the user would notice. Another option would be to show a clarification pop-up on-screen, on *CTRL+F*; or a by-standard clarification.

Comment: Who would put some notification like this on his website? I think hiding them by something else than display:none and just searching everywhere is way easier and usable

Comment: I might have a little trouble understanding how to implement your code. If perhaps you could explain a MWE a bit more? Thanks again. --- My replies, concerning the *CTRL+F*-invoked visibility of all hidden content, is regarding a page containing **hidden divs**, e.g. **[in this JSFiddle-toggler-example](http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/bQ8G3/)**. At the moment, one can't search the hidden text, when the Toggler is closed. On a page containing many such Togglers, it would be handy to somehow automatically open all Togglers, instead of having to open them manually separately.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/jssv8ctp/ shows how the text stays searchable (This it what the question asked for) But it doesn't open the togglers, yes. This will be hard to implement as you don't have an event to handle when a word is marked by the search. I have to admit that I don't have a solution for that edit: I don't think there is: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23479237/get-selected-element-from-browser-search