# Get selected element from browser search

Tags: javascript, css, browser

I would like to get the currently highlighted element that the browser search is actively highlighting. Is this possible?

My use case is, I have a collapsible Table of Contents with font-size 0, and when they search something, if it is in the ToC, it would be listed as a result. But since its font-size is 0, it would not be visible, so I would like to expand that section of the ToC.

Comment: It's not possible. And hiding elements by changing their font size to 0 is... an unusual approach.

Comment: The browser doesn't let you know which text is selected by search